# Error in cronjob via ssh server

Tags: php, ssh, cron

I am trying to set connect cron job via ssh server. i am using command but displaying " no such file or directory ". How can i do this ? Here is my command

/1 * * * * /var/www/html/mysite.com/cron/cron.php

Comment: remove `/` before 1 * *.. and check if you have file execution permission for `crop.php`

Comment: are you trying to run this cron every one minute?

Comment: @Lynn Rey : yes i want to execute after every 1 minute

Comment: @pardeepkaur did you try my method in the answer that I posted?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to run this cron every minute. Looks like sh script is not getting the correct location of your cron file. I would suggest adding these lines in your cron job.

```
CRONPATH=/var/www/html/mysite.com/cron
*/1     *   *   *   *   cd $CRONPATH; php cron.php
```